# Jupyter notebook core bugging maiby caused by tornado Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, raspberry-pi, tornado

I just installes jupyter on my Raspberry pi and I have few bugs...
First when I am on the notebook, I can't connect to the core so I can't execute the code meanwhile on the terminal an error is repeting in a loop:

```css
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ jupyter-notebook
/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/kernels/kernelmanager.py:18: VisibleDeprecationWarning: zmq.eventloop.minitornado is deprecated in pyzmq 14.0 and will be removed.
Install tornado itself to use zmq with the tornado IOLoop.

from jupyter_client.session import Session
[I 19:05:42.232 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/pi
[I 19:05:42.233 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.1.6 is running at:
[I 19:05:42.233 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=5006d2d91122d7374ae280dec90c364ca31ba4a40feaf4da
[I 19:05:42.233 NotebookApp] or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=5006d2d91122d7374ae280dec90c364ca31ba4a40feaf4da
[I 19:05:42.233 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 19:05:42.811 NotebookApp]

To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
file:///home/pi/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-1537-open.html
Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
http://localhost:8888/?token=5006d2d91122d7374ae280dec90c364ca31ba4a40feaf4da
or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=5006d2d91122d7374ae280dec90c364ca31ba4a40feaf4da
[I 19:06:31.639 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 28fe6304-92e3-422c-be53-007ffb43bbca, name: python3
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", mod_spec)
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipykernel/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
from .connect import *
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipykernel/connect.py", line 13, in <module>
from IPython.core.profiledir import ProfileDir
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
from .terminal.embed import embed
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/terminal/embed.py", line 18, in <module>
from IPython.terminal.interactiveshell import TerminalInteractiveShell
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/terminal/interactiveshell.py", line 20, in <module>
from prompt_toolkit.shortcuts import create_prompt_application, create_eventloop, create_prompt_layout, create_output
ImportError: cannot import name 'create_prompt_application' from 'prompt_toolkit.shortcuts' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/prompt_toolkit/shortcuts/__init__.py)
[I 19:06:40.614 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), keep random ports
```

Here is the complete error: https://dpaste.org/DLf3

So I'm gone on internet I fond some hypothetical solutions:
type "sudo pip3 install tornado==5.1.1" or upgrade jupyter but that's dosen't work I think that the error is caused by tornado :

```css
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ jupyter --version
jupyter core     : 4.7.0
jupyter-notebook : 6.1.6
qtconsole        : 4.3.1
ipython          : not installed
ipykernel        : 4.9.0
jupyter client   : 6.1.7
/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_server/services/kernels/kernelmanager.py:19: VisibleDeprecationWarning: zmq.eventloop.minitornado is deprecated in pyzmq 14.0 and will be removed.
    Install tornado itself to use zmq with the tornado IOLoop.
    
  from jupyter_client.session import Session
jupyter lab      : 3.0.0
nbconvert        : 6.0.7
ipywidgets       : not installed
nbformat         : 5.0.8
traitlets        : 4.3.2
```

tornado is also cause an error
Thank you in advance for the futur help provided...

Comment: Have you tried ```pip install tornado```?

Comment: Please add your output as text. Screenshots of text are not acceptable on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yes @DapperDuck , I tried pip3 install tornado==5.1.1

Comment: And sorry @KlausD. I didn't know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

type:
`sudo pip install 'prompt-toolkit==3.0.0'`
then:
`pip3 install --upgrade --user jupyter-console`
If you want more details : https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_console/issues/158